# getJSON call fails within iframe for internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, iframe, getjson

I am running a small webpage on *domainA* that loads some data using

```
 $.getJSON('http://domainA/data?callback=?', function ( data ) { // do stuff });
```

Now, I wanted to integrate this webpage on *domainB* using an iFrame. This also works perfectly well for Firefox and Chrome. However, the call fails for Internet Explorer 11. Using an iframe in *domainA* there is no problem at all. So I suspect that the problem is related to some cross domain restrictions and I tried to solve it by adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://domainA` to the response header which unfortunately did not help.

I am also confused why this should cause a cross domain problem as the code is running withing an iframe.

For the sake of clarity, I would like to give a more complete example. I have the following code on *domainB*

```
<iframe src="http://domainA"></iframe>
```

while on *domainA* I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var url = "http://domainA/api/data.json";
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    console.info(data);
  }).error(function (xhr, textStatus) {
    console.info(textStatus);
  });
});
```

If I load the page `http://domainB` using internet explorer then I get 'parsererror' in the console. On every other browser, I get the expected data output.

Comment: Look up same origin policy.

Comment: Isn't it the case that the page loaded withing the iframe already has the origin _domainA_?